# How to communicate between two widgets inside one QObject that is created in QMainWindow

Tags: python, pyside

I have problem regarding Signals and Slots in Qt. Let’s say I have three Classes, and methods in it as it is below (ignoring creation of GUI and some other things):

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *


class MainWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button1 = QPushButton("Create Car Control!")

        self.mdiArea = QMdiArea()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.mdiArea)
        layout.addWidget(self.button1)

        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.createCar)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("TEST!")

    def createCar(self):
        car1 = CarControl(self)
        tireWind = car1.getTireWind()
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(tireWind)
        tireWind.show()


class CarControl(QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CarControl, self).__init__()

        self.tire = TireWind(parent)
        self.tire.show()
        self.tire.empty_tire.connect(self.printProblem)

    def getTireWind(self):
        return self.tire

    @Slot(str)
    def printProblem(self, probl):
        print(probl)


class TireWind(QWidget):

    empty_tire = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TireWind, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button_emptyTire = QPushButton("Empty Tire")
        self.button_emptyTire.clicked.connect(self.sendEmptyTireSignal)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button_emptyTire)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("TIRE")

    def sendEmptyTireSignal(self):
        print("I'm in")
        self.empty_tire.emit("EMPTY TIRE")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is short version of code. In `MainWindow` I have `mdiArea` and I am creating object that controls everything that happens in Car Windows (`CarControl`) and I add its QWidget `TireWind` as subWindow in `mdiArea`.
 Thing is when I click on `button_emptyTire` in my subWindow `TireWind` it should emit signal `empty_tire` and my “controller” `CarControl` should recognize it and run method `printProblem`. But I’m not achieving it.
How can I communicate between `TireWind` and `CarControl`?
I'm having multiple QWidgets in CarControl so I was thinking managing all between its widgets inside `CarControl`

Hope it's enough of code to understand the problem :)

EDIT:
I made a typo: It should be: `self.tire.empty_tire.connect(self.printProblem)` instead `self.tire.sendEmptyTireSignal.connect(self.printProblem)`.

EDIT2:
Edited code so it is runnable.

It still does not work! :(

Comment: Typo: change `self.tire.sendEmptyTireSignal.connect(self.printProblem)` to `self.tire.empty_tire.connect(self.printProblem)`

Comment: Indeed I did, I copy it wrong. But it still does not work :(

Answer (score 2):

You're connecting a function to a Slot with this line:

```
self.tire.sendEmptyTireSignal.connect(self.printProblem)
```

instead it should read

```
self.tire.empty_tire.connect(self.printProblem)
```

because `empty_tire` is the signal you want to connect your slot to.

**Edit:**

With the new code what seems to be happening is that the Garbage collector is cleaning up your CarControl object. This causes your signal to be disconnected because the QObject doesn't exist anymore. You can fix this by putting it into a list for example:

```
class MainWindow(QDialog):
    cars = []

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...

    def createCar(self):
        car1 = CarControl(self)
        # append it to the list so the object is still referenced
        self.cars.append(car1)
        tireWind = car1.getTireWind()
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(tireWind)

        tireWind.show()
```

Comment: Indeed I did, I copy it wrong. But it still does not work :(

Comment: Could you provide a runnable example ? The code in your question is missing some things so I can't tell you why it doesnt work. Alternatively if theres an error post the entire traceback.

Comment: I edited my code and it is runnable. There are no any error. When I push button  "Create Car Control!" it creates window "TireWind" and inside that window when you push button "Empty Tire" it should print: "I'm in", and "EMPTY TIRE", but it does not print "EMPTY TIRE"

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It was silly mistake.

instead of:

```
class CarControl(QObject):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(CarControl, self).__init__()
```

it should go:

```
class CarControl(QObject):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(CarControl, self).__init__(parent)
```

I wasn’t passing **parent** to QObject, so it probably couldn't reference anywhere or something like that.
so yeah, that's it.

Comment: Ah nice, certainly a more elegant way to fix it.